# Rebus & Structuremap timeouts issue

Tags: rebus

I'm seeing an issue where timeouts never fire. I'm seeing calls through my implementation of IContainerAdapter.GetHandlerInstancesFor that look like rebus internals.  Could the fact that I'm not returning anything for those calls be messing things up? If so what do I need to return?

Comment: could you maybe elaborate some more about your setup, e.g. how is Rebus configured?

Comment: The problem turned out to be in my NHibernate timeout manager. I thought I was running the in memory store rather than my own.  SQLite (which I used for testing) has different locking semantics than MS SqlServer.